# With std::vector, why is &vec[0] undefined behavior, but vec.data() safe?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, vector, undefined-behavior

I've been reading through the FAQ at isocpp.org at ["Link here"](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/containers#vector-is-contiguous) and came across the caution that with an `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<int> v;
auto a = &v[0]; // Is undefined behaviour but
auto a = v.data(); // Is safe
```

From the actual site:

```
void g()
{
  std::vector<Foo> v;
  // ...
  f(v.begin(), v.size());  // Error, not guaranteed to be the same as &v[0]
    ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑ // Cough, choke, gag; use v.data() instead
}
```

> Also, using `&v[0]` is undefined behavior if the `std::vector` or
>   `std::array` is empty, while it is always safe to use the `.data()`
>   function.

I'm not sure I've understood this exactly. `::data()` returns a pointer to the beginning of the array, and `&[0]` returns the address of the beginning. I'm not seeing the difference here, and I don't think that `&[0]` is dereferencing anything (i.e., is not reading the memory at element 0). On Visual Studio in debug build accessing subscript `[0]` results in an assertion failed, but in release mode it doesn't say anything. Also the addresses in both cases is 0 for the default constructed vector.

Also I don't understand the comment about `::begin()` not guaranteed to be the same as `::operator[0]`. I assumed that for a vector the raw pointer in the `begin()` iterator, `::data()`, and `&[0]` were all the same value.

Comment: This is by no means "official", but think about it. Pointers are much more permissible than references. A pointer value need not represent an object, while a reference *must* refer to an object.

Comment: well if it is empty then there is no zero index and the data array may or may not have been created for the vector

Comment: Iterators and pointers are not the same thing.

Comment: also if your vector contains objects, they may have overridden `&` operator

Comment: He really emphasizes that data() is safe and &[0] is not, it's in this section https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/containers#vector-is-contiguous

Comment: The point is that v[0], i.e. without the parentheses, is UB..., because you are explicitly asking for an element which does not exist.

Comment: @Andre So in other words you can point to an invalid address  but not take it with &.

Comment: @Zebrafish. Exactly, you can have a pointer with an invalid adress and the dereferencing is UB, not the pointer it self. In the case of &v[0] you are asking for a non-existing element (with v[0]), which is UB. And then afterwards, you try to get the address of it (with &), but by then you have already triggered UB.

Comment: @André do you have a reference to claim this ? afaik, if you're talking about the pointer case, p[0] is an lvalue, and & takes an lvalue; no lvalue-to-prvalue conversion occur, no UB is invoked as long as p+0 does not. See [cwg issue #232](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#232) for further info (of course, the vector case is still UB, but for a different reason)

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes [expr.unary.op]/1 only defines the behavior of `*` when the expression actually points to an object or function. It follows that the dereference is UB by omission - at least until core issue 232 is actually resolved.

Comment: @T.C. ah, for some reason I thought 232 had already been resolved, sorry :)

Comment: I think it is worth note that &v[0] is only UB in the example because it occurs right after the vector is defined.  At that point the vector is empty.  &v[0] is not UB after something is done to the vector that creates some data in the vector.  I have never even though about calling &v[0] before adding elements to the vector or sizing the vector to copy to it.  I don't think I can dream up a use case for the code in the post.

Answer (score 32):

> I'm not seeing the difference here

`&v[0]` is same as `&(v[0])`, i.e. get the address from the 1st element of `v`. But when `v` is empty there're no elements at all, `v[0]` just leads to UB, it's trying to return a non-existent element; trying to get the address from it doesn't make sense.

[`v.data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) is always safe. It will return the pointer to the underlying array directly. When `v` is empty the pointer is still valid (it might be null pointer or not); but note that dereferencing it (like `*v.data()`) leads to UB too, the same as `v[0]`.

> Also I don't understand the comment about `::begin()` not guaranteed to be the same as `::operator[0]`

[`std::vector::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin) will return an iterator with type [`std::vector::iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector#Member_types), which must satisfy the requirement of [RandomAccessIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator). It might be a raw pointer, but it doesn't have to be. It's acceptable to implement it as a class.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding references and pointers, because I really thought & returned the address, which is assignable to a pointer.

Comment: @Zebrafish Yes `operator&` does return the address, the problem is that it's trying to return the address of an inexistent element.

Comment: @songyuanyao I deleted my answer because it got downvoted (and I'm too lazy to defend it :)) yet I still believe the first part of your answer is not correct; you *can* dereference a null pointer as long as no lvalue to prvalue conversion occurs; so, there's nothing in the language forbidding a *potential* implementation of vector to make &v[0] to always equal data() ... so your explanation is either incomplete or incorrect

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes I hoped you would explain it more (with the cited standard) in your answer. :) Well, I checked the standard, which doesn't define the behavior when the `vector` is empty. That means any behavior is acceptable. On the other hand, the standard guarantees that `v.data()` is always valid even when it's empty; I think it's the biggest difference between the 2 cases from the aspect of the standard.

Comment: @songyuanyao yes, I do agree that &v[0] is UB whenever v.empty() is true. The problem is your explanation, that seems suggesting that it is so *because* you cannot "return the address of an inexistent element". AFAIK, this is not true; see [[expr.unary:1,2,3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.unary#op-1)] and [[expr.add:4,7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.add#7)]

Comment: @songyuanyao see also [cwg issue #232](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#232) for further info

Comment: @songyuanyao sorry, for some reason I though 232 had already been resolved in latest standards ... but I was wrong; it is indeed UB, sorry again :)

Comment: @songyuanyao +1 But you don't give the precise reason why `&v[0]` is UB for empty `v`, from a standard perspective. `v[n]` is defined as `*(v.begin() + n)` in sequence.reqmts. If `v` is empty, then `v.begin()` (or equivalently, `v.begin() + 0`, is not dereferencable, therefore `*v.begin()` is UB (iterator.requirements.general/5).

Answer (score 2):

The information missing in your question for your example to be more understandable is that `void f(Foo* array, unsigned numFoos);` Calling `.begin()` on your vector of `Foo` is not guaranteed to be a *pointer*. But some implementations might behave like it enough for it to work.

In the empty vector case, `v.data()`, returns a pointer but you don't know what it points to. It could be a nullptr, but that is not guaranteed.

Comment: To illustrate the statement about `v.data()` on empty vector: see [this test with g++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/725b7dc0774dce87). Note how in one case it returns null pointer, in another it returns non-null.

Answer (score 1):

It all comes down to one simple thing: You can add or subtract an integral value to the pointer, but trying to dereference an invalid pointer is undefined behaviour.

Say for example,

```
int a[10];
int* p = a;
int* q = p + 10;   // This is fine
int r = *(p + 10)  // This is undefined behaviour
```

In your example: `v[0]` is the same as `*(v's internal pointer+0)`, and this is a problem if the vector is empty.

Comment: This is my trouble in understanding, I get that v[0] reads the memory at v[0] but thought that &v[0] simply gets the address of that location. Obviously I'm wrong.

Comment: v[0] does not only provide a value but also a reference to some memory location, like some kind of window to it. To do that it has to interpret this location content appropriately - and if it can't , well thats UB. The pointer just care about address - it doesnt care what bytes are stored under some address.

Comment: @Zebrafish You are not wrong, `v[0]` _does not_ read any memory, instead it dereferences invalid pointer. Dereferencing by itself does not do anything unlit you read or write this value, but C++ still does not allow this. But it _could_ allow this. Techically, there is nothing stopping your code from working.

Comment: As long as there is an element in the vector, &v[0] works.  I use this construction all the time, but only after resizing the vector to the size I need it to be.  Resizing allocates the memory, and &v[0] is perfectly safe at that point.  In light of this discussion, I may switch to .data() henceforth, but I'm not going to go back and change old code...